# Segue from Storyboard to XIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

I have a storyboard View Controller, which is the first screen in my app. The rest of the app is designed with xib's. I want to segue from a button in the storyboard's VC to a XIB file. I know how to do this from a xib to storyboard, but how about this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**From xib to storyboard**

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

then

```
[self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:initViewController animated:YES];
```

**From storyboard to xib**

```
YourViewController *viewController=[[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerName" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In case of NavigatinController

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: When i try to go from storyboard to xib, i et this error: `FruitsMemoryGame[1588:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<WelcomeViewController 0x16598a70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnHighScores.'`

Comment: Oh i forgot to import the classes. It's working now, thanks a lot :)

Comment: that is due to a broken IBOutlet or IBAction

Comment: I don't understand your porting going from xib to storyboard. So to have xib view `dog` segue to ViewController `forest`, I am not clear on how you know which view `initViewController` is pointing to. I am here guessing that you are coming from a viewController `house` that contains an instance of `dog`.

Comment: in storyboard you set a starting point and that is what we get in `initViewController ` by using `[storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController]`

Comment: What if the .xib's class is a UIView subclass and not a UIViewController subclass ?